# Why are Common Lisp functions visible outside an enclosing let?

Tags: common-lisp

In Scheme, the function `f` below is not visible outside its enclosing `let`:

```lisp
(let ()
  (define (f x)
    (+ x 1)))

(f 2)  ; Error.
```

However, in Common Lisp, the function `f` is visible outside its enclosing `let`:

```lisp
(let ()
  (defun f (x)
    (+ x 1)))

(f 2)  ; Returns: 3
```

What is going on in the Common Lisp code above? How can `f` be visible outside the `let`?

Comment: because CL is a dynamic language (an assembler on steroids), whereas Scheme is static. so in Scheme `define` is a lexical construct but in CL it is an imperative command, affecting the global <s>environment</s> functions namespace -- don't forget that CL is Lisp-2.

Comment: Scheme and Common Lisp are different languages, using one as a guide for the other will frequently end up in frustration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From common lisp hyperspec:

Evaluating `defun` causes function-name to be a global name for the function specified by the lambda expression

```
 (lambda lambda-list
   [[declaration* | documentation]]
   (block block-name form*))
```

processed in the lexical environment in which `defun` was executed.

http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_defun.htm#defun

If you want a local definitions use `flet` or `labels`.

In the case of scheme, `define` is local to the `<body>` in which it is defined.

Answer (score 6):

In Scheme the `define` operator can be used both for top level definitions **and** for internal definitions. For internal definitions these should appear at the beginning of a *body* and it will have an effect like a `letrec*` form. See chapter 5.3 in R7RS.

In Common Lisp `defun` always defines a global function. To define local lexical functions Common Lisp has two other operators: `flet` and `labels`. `labels` is used for recursive functions.